# After select some checkboxes, make some tests and disply the output: R shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

The basic question (which I think is very easy, but I can't get to it): I have a Shiny app which allows you to upload an excel file, then set some variables. I want to create 3 checkboxes with 3 tests and then, after selecting the first test (for e.g.) to select the checkboxes of which variable to make the test, and after, the output of the tests:

[Something like this (which I already have done):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O4Wi.png)

I have tried something like this:

```
  output$Stattest = renderUI({
     checkboxGroupInput("Stattest", "Choose test for stationarity", choices = c("ADF","PP","KPSS-TREND"))
  })
  
  
  output$varSTAT = renderUI({
    if (is.null(datos())){
      return(NULL)}
    variables = colnames(datos())
    div(class = "row-fluid",
        
        div(class="span1",checkboxGroupInput("Var", strong("Variables for stationarity test",style = "color:green"), variables)),
    )
  })
  
  adf <- reactive({


    if(input$Stattest == "ADF"){
   
     
      adf.test(df_sel()[[input$Var]])
    
     
    }})

  
  output$ADF=renderPrint({
    adf()
  })
```

The code from above prints only one output (just for one variable) and if I select another variable, the error is: `subset2: attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex`. I think to use some with `lapply` but I don't know exactly how.

I have tried also:

```
 adf <- reactive({


    if(input$Stattest == "ADF"){
   
     for(i in length(input$Var))
      adf.test(datos()[[input$Var[[i]]]])
    
     
    }})
```

But...I do not know how to print the outputs.

The "major" problem is that I need to have a reactive function, because this outputs would be listed in a report (Rnw).
Thanks in advance! :) :D

Comment: Can you make this post completely reproducible by including complete code and relevant data? what would be your expected output? Do you want to apply `adf.test` to every value in `input$Var` ?

Comment: Hi :) The complete code would not be helpful....Yes, I want to apply ```adf.test``` for every value that is selected from checkbox (input$Var) and then to print the output of the ```adf.test```. So for example, I have 3 variables (a, b, c) which will be printed as checkboxes, and after I select de checkboxes (all three ) the ```adf.test``` will   be realized (for each 3 variables) and then will be printed 3 outputs (for ```adf.test(a)``` and so on). I hope this is clear.....Thank you very much for involvement!

Comment: Does something like this work : `if(input$Stattest == "ADF"){ lapply(input$Var, function(x) adf.test(df_sel()[[x]])) }` ?

Comment: No :(...```missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed```

Comment: If I have something like this ```
      lapply(df_sel()[[input$Var]], function(x) 
      {
        adf.test(df_sel()[[x]]) })``` works, but does not print anything and if I check another variable(a and b at the some time) is the error: ```subset2: no such index at level 1```. :)